# Pass block to registrations controller, devise_token_auth syntax?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have User and Admin classes, which will have an associated Profile as a polymorphic has_one.  I've found an example with vanilla devise that will build the profile in the new method for the User class, but if I try to override that method nothing happens.

In [the devise token auth documentation](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth) it says that you can pass a block to the controller you want to extend and that block will run after the controller performs its standard function.  The example looks like this:

```
class Custom::RegistrationsController < DeviseTokenAuth::RegistrationsController

  def create
    super do |resource|
      resource.do_something(extra)
    end
  end

end
```

I need help sorting out what the syntax of this looks like.  I need to call build_profile in the create method, but I can't get anything to happen no matter what I put in the do block.  If I run anything outside that block it runs when the registrations controller is called (and I can see that it is my controller getting called in the logs.)

So, how do I call build_profile in a block passed to super, is the question.

Comment: Where is `build_profile` defined? If it's on the resource, just call that method on the resource in the block. Have you tried debugging by adding byebug in the code block?

Comment: Hey Nathan, I ended up just overriding the entire controller, copying the code into said controller, and adding the one line.  I attempted every theoretical syntax I could come up with, but I think I'm missing something.  I haven't been able to find any examples of functional overrides of any kind, but overriding the entire controller worked.  The docs for this gem are really lacking in specifics, so if you're unsure of what you're doing (as is my case) every little thing is a day long nightmare. :\